# Dead locking Issue

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a Microsoft Word application with an SQL Server Back end.  The application has about 100 users that use about 50 forms to update and select information from tables in the SQL database.  One of the tables continues to lock up on us.  The table will be completely locked until our DBA kills the session that locked.  The DBA told us that one session is blocking the other session.  Does anyone know how to protect against this locking issue?

Comment: Deadlocks can happen for a multitude of reasons. I would start by getting the DBA to give you the deadlock graph (an XML representation of the circumstances surrounding the deadlock). It will help you identify which statements are causing the issue.

Comment: We will need more information about the deadlock. Can you post the exact schema of the tables involved, the exact T-SQL statements and the deadlock graph? See [How to: Save Deadlock Graphs (SQL Server Profiler)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/save-deadlock-graphs-sql-server-profiler). With this information you can receive guidance how to fix the deadlock.

Comment: There is a difference between blocking and a deadlock.  A deadlock is where two (or more) sessions are blocking each other and neither can proceed until the other releases their lock.  This is a situation that SQL Server can detect and will automatically resolve.  If your DBA has to intervene, it's just regular blocking and perhaps an orphaned session.  An orphaned session can happen when a user gets tired of waiting for a query to return and just kills the application without cancelling the query.  In this case the transaction stays open and the locks are held.

Comment: The DBA just told me that the deadlock trace was not on so there is no way to capture the deadlock graph.  He said he would add a trace flag for the future.  I am kinda inexperienced in this area but does this make sense?  Is there anyway I can solve my issue if I do not have the deadlock graph?

Comment: Do you at least know what statement is blocking which other statement? If you know that and can provide that code in this post as well, there might be some insight that can be lent.

Comment: my advise would be: avoid blob columns ! and use WITH(NOLOCK) when you can read safely. that saved my own locking problems for years.

Comment: From what the DBA told me, it was caused by an update query and a delete  command.  We are not using any blob columns in our database.  On the suggestion about WITH(NOLOCK), from my understanding but this could be wrong is that with a WITH(NOLOCK) it might skip records that it was suppose to delete.  This would cause problems for us because our stored procedures run every 30 minutes and other insert statements need those deletes to be correct.

Comment: I ended up taking each one of the queries that hit the table and running a display estimation execution plan against them.  Per the results, I added any index that was needed.  The issue has not occurred since.

Comment: @dluck You should post this as an answer to your own question so it doesn't appear on the "unanswered" feed

Answer (score 0):

The question was answered in the comments, I'm answering here so it doesn't fill the `Unanswered` feed. dluck, you should probably post your own answer to the question and accept it.

Generate an estimated execution plan and use it to determine if you need indexes on your tables. Likewise, using `WITH(NOLOCK)` introduces some risk in the form of potentially skipped rows on deletion but should be safe for the most part. Using a combination of indexes and `WITH(NOLOCK)` clauses should prevent DB blocks.